# Neo4j - Indexes and performance

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, database-indexes

I have a doubt on the performances of a Cypher query in Neo4j.
The situation is: every node of my graph has a property and I'd like to count the number of nodes with the same property.
So, my basic query is

```
match (n:NodeLabel)
with n.community as community, n.myid as myid
match (m) where m.community = community
return myid, count(m) as totcommunity
```

I created an index on the property "community"

```
create index on :NodeLabel(Community)
```

But the performances are very poor: it takes ages for a graph with 200.000 nodes.
How can I get better performances?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the label for the second match, then it cannot use the index:
Try this:

```
match (n:NodeLabel)
match (m:NodeLabel) where m.community = n.community
return n.myid as myid, count(*) as totcommunity
```

You can also make sure that it uses the index by prefixing your query with `EXPLAIN` and check the query plan.

Comment: Thanks for the EXPLAIN clause (I didn't know it). But what if I have different labels for nodes and I'd want to check the community property for all of them? Are you telling me that if I don't specify a label for the node, it won't use the index for the specified property?

Comment: I don't understand how to use the EXPLAIN clause. Could you provide an example? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return each distinct community value and the number of nodes with that value:

```
MATCH (n:NodeLabel)
RETURN n.community, COUNT(n);
```

If, instead, you want to get the count of the number of nodes with the same `community` value as a specific node (as identified my `myid`), try this query:

```
MATCH (n:NodeLabel {myid: 123})
WITH n.community AS c, n.myid AS myid
MATCH (n:NodeLabel)
WHERE n.community = c
RETURN myid, n.community, COUNT(n);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it should work. But I want for specific nodes the size of the community they belong to, not the size of all communities.

Comment: Yes it is. But the problem was about using the desired label when matching nodes. Thanks a lot for your answer